# can I set specific tcp window size on accepted socket or is it system wide approach and can't be set on accepted or listening socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I think I read somewhere that tcp window size is system wide settings or can be set with ethtool or something. But I like to know can it be also set on every accepted socket fd with setSockopt

Can it speed up the load or reponse of a connection and data transfer if I am also using TCP cork on accepted socket?

Or does it make sense to increase the tcp window size to achieve any speed of data transfer because I am assuming if tcp window is huge then buffering will increase that in turn slows down the data transfer.

Or is there any other settings I need to set on accepted socket? please do let me know
Thanks for any info

Comment: You can set `SO_RCVBUF` using `setsockopt` just fine.

Comment: @Cheatah should I set `SO_RCVBUF` on accepted socket or listening socket?